# Where to put certificates cacert.pem for cURL?

Tags: curl, rvm, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to update rvm on a Debian server :

```
rvm get stable
```

but I got the folowing error :

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here : http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

I installed this servers about 5 month ago and everything was working fine, but it seems that something changed on the certificate of https://rvm.io

So I managed to download a new bundle certificate (cacert.pem in my user directory) :

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

And try a different command as the [official doc](https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading/) says, but with a option for the certificate file to use :

```
\curl --cacert ./cacert.pem -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable # update to stable
```

Things moved a bit forward. Unfortunately later on, rvm run again curl during the install process and I got again the same error.

**So I was wondering where to put my cacert.pem file to replace theone used by cURL ?**

I tried as well other technics :
creating a .curlrc file containing cacert = ~/cacert.pem
but I got an error :
    CAfile: cacert.pem
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

So I tried to copy my cacert.pem in /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org
and made a sym link in /etc/ssl/certs that point to /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org/cacert.pem

But, when I

```
rvm get stable
```

I got the error :

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here : http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

I also tried this below, without different result though :

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

**So I am wondering where to put my cacert.pem file ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I managed to make it works, but I'm not very happy with my solution.

First mistake I was making is that the instruction in the .curlrc file was incorrect.
We should use this file the same way we specify options to the "curl" command.
So I removed the "equal sign" :

```
cacert /home/user_me/cacert.pem
```

With this I was able to make the first part of the command to work :

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

The bash part was still failing because rvm was using curl again in root mode.

So I copied my **.curlrc** file as well into the **/root** folder.

And it worked !
I could even call the standard rvm command :

```
rvm get stable
```

But this is a bit tricky, and I would prefer that curl use my cacert.pem file without all those .curlrc files.

Googling more, I found some usefull information [here](http://blog.nowherelan.com/category/linux/ubuntu-linux/hardy/) and [here](http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/curl-adding-installing-trusting-new-self-signed-certificate/).
The first reference has a little mistake :
When I read the man page of "sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh" command, I realized the guy was puting his file at wrong place.

You have to put your certificate into **/usr/share/ca-certificates** folder instead of /usr/local/share/ca-certificates , and then append a line for your certificate into the configuration file **/etc/ca-certificates.conf** (e.g., “my_ca.crt“).
Then you may run your "sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh" command.

Note : If you copy your certificate to the **/usr/local/share/ca-certificates** instead, then you don't need anymore to modify the /etc/ca-certificates.conf configuration file nor run the "sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh" command.

However in my case, for the first solution (/usr/share/ca-certificates) I got an error when I ran the "sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh" command.
As second solution, I tried just to put my certificate into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates. But it didn't work.

So I gave up and I kept my two .curlrc files.

So if anybody could point what I was doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Sure but the goal when using a certificate is to make things secure. If you use the '-k' parameter. You will allow insecure SSL connection. Extract from the man page : **-k, --insecure (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers.**

Comment: Yes, but if all you care about is getting it done (applies to most people, I think), -k is an option.